# xampp icons on chrome tabs when running wamp

Tags: apache, wamp

I was using XAAMP but i was having some problems (XAAMP localhost was taking some time to update everytime i changed something on my code) so i decided to try WAMP.

I uninstalled XAAMP without any problem (i think!) and **installed WAMP**. I created a small app in "www" folder of WAMP and runned it on localhost and i did **notice that the small icon on my browser tab was still XAAMP orange icon.**

I surf the web for solutions and i found that i need to stop Apache from Windows services. I look in my service's list but i couldn't find it.

Anybody knows what i have to do ?

Comment: Try refreshing your browser cache. Open the browser and do `CTRL+F5`

Comment: I cleared the cache but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Favicons are cached for quite a while, which is why you're still seeing it.

You could explicitly set a new favicon in your html to override the old XAAMP favicon, eg.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/chromeextentionsaremakingmemad.ico" />
```

in the `<head>` tag.

Also, clear your cache, or open a new incognito / private browsing tab to see it instantly after your change.

Comment: Okay ! I thought i might be running XAAMP instead of WAMP that why i asked but i see that after a while it will eventually change. Thanks !